# Has anyone made regular-themed version of the Star Trek Catan role cards?

Tags: catan

I see that "Star Trek" catan has some extra role cards, which add a new element to the game (and are the only things that do).  I'd like to try these, but I don't really like the "Star Trek" theme, and it's expensive.

Has anyone made some printable versions of these cards that fit the original Catan theme?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Star Trek theme](http://www.catan.com/game/star-trek-catan) included the German language mini-expansion [Die Helfer Von Catan](http://www.catan.com/game/die-helfer-von-catan) ("The Helpers of Catan")

An English translation is available as a [PDF on BGG](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/88118/helpers-of-catan-english-cards).