# Command cards (Star Trek Catan) for vanilla Catan?

Tags: catan, expansions

I played Star Trek Catan for the first time last night and really enjoyed what the command cards (Sulu, Kirk, Spock) added to the game.

I would like to purchase a deck of command cards themed to match regular Settlers of Catan. Does this exist in one of the expansions, or as a standalone?

Edit: Sorry, this is a duplicate of [Has anyone made regular-themed version of the Star Trek Catan role cards?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/has-anyone-made-regular-themed-version-of-the-star-trek-catan-role-cards?rq=1)